# "Вернуться к вопросу" - выделить ссылку?

Tags: обсуждение, дизайн, история-правок

Может стоит выделить ссылку синим с ховером, или поставить иконку треугольника? На первый взгляд воспринимается как обычный текст.

> [image: Вернуться к вопросу]

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, подобные предложения лучше делать на MSE — там их сразу видят разработчики движка.

Во-вторых, мне кажется, что вполне понятно, что данный текст является ссылкой. Обратите внимание: это не единственный элемент, который является ссылкой и не выделен как ссылка. Под вопросом например, есть ссылки "поделиться", "править", "закрыть" и т.п. Нет никакого смысла выделять одну из ссылок и оставлять другие невыделенными. А если выделять все — тогда будет интерфейс слишком перегружен.

Об этом писал Артемий сами-знаете-кто Лебедев. Подобный подход — "не подчёркивать ссылки и не выделять их цветом" — достаточно давно принят на вооружение самыми различными сайтами.

Comment: да, но у этих ссылок есть хотябы hover

Comment: а mse это куда?)

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко это вот [сюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Но писать придётся уже по-английски.

Comment: Только вот недавно этот подход с подчёркиванием ссылок был [несколько пересмотрен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314275/339911).

Comment: "достаточно давно принят на вооружение самыми различными сайтами" и поэтому теперь на многих сайтах хрен поймёшь, ссылка это или нет (:

Comment: @Suvitruf вот в советские времена-то ссылки были ого-го ...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ссылки должны выделяться нижним подчёркиванием! Всех в ссылку!

Comment: "Поделиться", "править" и "закрыть" не ссылки, а кнопки. Они не ведут на другую страницу, а вызывают какое-то действие на текущей.

Comment: @Эникейщик Простите, но они выглядят как самый обычный текст, поэтому назвать это "кнопкой" у меня лично язык не повернётся. Я человек простой: есть обводка - значит кнопка, нет - значит ссылка. Правда, в современном мире много нелогичного: метка например выглядит как кнопка, а не как текстовая метка.

Comment: Странно. То, что точно такой же текст является ссылкой вам понятно, а что кнопкой - нет.

Comment: Мне понятно, что является ссылкой, а что кнопкой. Если навести мышь на ссылку, то стрелка поменяется на палец.